# Problems making groupboxes visible/invisible C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two groupboxes stacked on each other.

By default the property "Visible" is set on false.

Outside the groupboxes I have a combobox which contain the name of the groupbox I want to make visible.
When the combobox index changes, all groupboxes will hide. And the selected index with related groupbox will get visible.

Somehow only the first if statement works and makes the related groupbox visible.
In the second if statement it does give the messagebox "test" but does not make the groupbox visible.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    invKindGroup.Visible = false;
    invTeamGroup.Visible = false;            

    if ((int)comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) {

        invKindGroup.Visible = true;
    }

    if ((int)comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) {

        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        invTeamGroup.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I have double checked on the correct names of `invKindGroup` and `invTeamGroup`

Comment: My crystal ball says your GroupBoxes are __not stacked after all but nested__. They tend to do that when you position them with the __mouse__. Move the 'top' one out with the mouse and then move it back with the __keyboard__!

Comment: @TaW your crystall ball was correct. Thanks